# How to push changes in git as dev branch without raising pull request

Tags: git

I have to create a branch that is separate from `master`. Now I want to create a `release` branch which contains some additional changes from `master` branch. How can I do that without raising an actual pull request.
I usually do

```
git checkout -b release
# Do my changes
git push release
```

Above generates a link that ask me to create a Merge/Pull request. Is there any way I can do it without creating PR? It's like my branch exist on remote but does not wants to be merged.

Comment: The creation of the pull request is predominantly a Git server side thing.  You would need to configure your Git provider (e.g. GitHub, Bitbucket, etc.) to not auto create a pull request in certain cases.

Comment: *Git* does not have or support pull or merge requests. Git*Hub* and *Bitbucket* provide pull requests. Git*Lab* provide merge requests. How and when and why each of these web-hosting sites makes you use a PR, rather than a direct push, is up to each web-hosting site. Pick which hosting site you care about and rewrite your question as needed, especially the tag ([tag:git] is for generic command-line Git operation, where pull requests simply do not exist).